# How to make an object usable in Unity's Terrain Paint Detail tool?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, terrain

[image]

Currently I have this object, with 1 material in the material folder.

But when I add it to the Paint Detail tool, and try to use it, it doesn't create a single one.

It would be a lot of time to add them to the terrain one by one, so I want to know how can I fix this.

If you want any informations about the files, just comment, thanks :)